# How to deploy dockerhub or redhat container catalog (external registries) images in minishift

Tags: openshift, minishift

I'm studying openshift from and administration perspective and it is costing me a lot to understand it and one thing that I want to do is to deploy known containers into it and all I can do with minishift is deploy examples it provides or push a local develop which is not helpful to my purpose but I can't find a 'how to' of linking minishift cdk (the one from redhat) to external repositories like dockerhub or registry.access.redhat.com

Any help will be really appreciated.

What I did was:

1. Connect to minishift docker service

### >    $ eval $(minishift docker-env)

2. Tried to pull from redhat container catalog.

> $ docker pull registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/jenkins-2-rhel7:3.11.98-6
>      Trying to pull repository registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/jenkins-2-rhel7 ... 
>      error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character 'F' looking for beginning of value: "File not found.\""
>
> $ docker pull registry.redhat.io/openshift3/jenkins-2-rhel7:3.11.98-6
>      Trying to pull repository registry.redhat.io/openshift3/jenkins-2-rhel7 ... 
>      unable to retrieve auth token: 401 unauthorized
>
> $ docker login registry.redhat.io
>      Username: ********
>      Password: 
>      WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/cesar.cabral/.docker/config.json.
>      Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
>
> Login Succeeded
>
> $ docker pull registry.redhat.io/openshift3/jenkins-2-rhel7:3.11.98-6
>      Trying to pull repository registry.redhat.io/openshift3/jenkins-2-rhel7 ...
>
> ### >    error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character 'F' looking for beginning of value: "File not found.\""

3. tried the same but with dockerhub, no luck either.

> $ docker pull hub.docker.com/nginx:1.17.0
>     Trying to pull repository hub.docker.com/nginx ... 
>     Pulling repository hub.docker.com/nginx
>     invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value

Comment: The `docker pull` command is only pulling into your local `docker` daemon, not minishift. See https://cookbook.openshift.org/deploying-applications-from-images/how-do-i-deploy-a-pre-existing-application-image.html and https://cookbook.openshift.org/image-registry-and-image-streams/how-do-i-import-an-image-from-an-external-image.html

Comment: Thank you, I will giveit a read. I just managed to do it in minikube so it must be similar.